# Avoid overlapping axis labels in R

Tags: r, plot, overlap

I want to plot data in a graph with larger font-size for the lables.

```
x = c(0:10)
y = sin(x) + 10

plot (
    x, y, type="o",
    xlab = "X values",
    ylab = "Y values",
    cex.axis = "2",
    cex.lab = "2",
    las = 1
)
```

Unfortunately the numbers on the y-axis overlap the label for the y-axis. I tried to use mar, but that did not work (By the way, how can I find out which graphic parameters can be directly used in the plot command and which have to be set with the par()-method? ).

How can I avoid that labels overlap?

Thanks for your help.

Sven

Comment: Note: If you like to move the axis label, print it separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506046/how-do-i-put-more-space-between-the-axis-labels-and-axis-title-in-an-r-boxplot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `par(mar)` to increase the plot margins and `par(mgp)` to move the axis label.

```
par(mar = c(6.5, 6.5, 0.5, 0.5), mgp = c(5, 1, 0))
#Then call plot as before
```

---

In the help page `?par` it explains which parameters can be used directly in `plot` and which must be called via `par`.

> There are several parameters can only be set by a call to ‘par()’:
>
> ```
>     • ‘"ask"’,
>
>     • ‘"fig"’, ‘"fin"’,
>
>     • ‘"lheight"’,
>
>     • ‘"mai"’, ‘"mar"’, ‘"mex"’, ‘"mfcol"’, ‘"mfrow"’, ‘"mfg"’,
>
>     • ‘"new"’,
>
>     • ‘"oma"’, ‘"omd"’, ‘"omi"’,
>
>     • ‘"pin"’, ‘"plt"’, ‘"ps"’, ‘"pty"’,
>
>     • ‘"usr"’,
>
>     • ‘"xlog"’, ‘"ylog"’
>
>  The remaining parameters can also be set as arguments (often via
>  ‘...’) to high-level plot functions such as ‘plot.default’,
>  ‘plot.window’, ‘points’, ‘lines’, ‘abline’, ‘axis’, ‘title’,
>  ‘text’, ‘mtext’, ‘segments’, ‘symbols’, ‘arrows’, ‘polygon’,
>  ‘rect’, ‘box’, ‘contour’, ‘filled.contour’ and ‘image’.  Such
>  settings will be active during the execution of the function,
>  only.  However, see the comments on ‘bg’ and ‘cex’, which may be
>  taken as _arguments_ to certain plot functions rather than as
>  graphical parameters.
> ```

Comment: When I use mgp the y-label as well as the x-label are moved. Is it also possible do move only the y-label? Is there a good tutorial that teaches those basic things? I always get lost in the help,... :-(

Comment: If you don't like the default placement than the usual approach is `ylab=""` and use `axis(... , line=<integer>)`. ?axis

Comment: @DWin: I will try your suggestion. Now I first set ´par (mgp)´ the the title for one axis, then ´par(mgp)´ again, and the ´title()´ for the bext axis.

Answer (score 3):

The quick and dirty way would be to use `par` and add a newline in `ylab`, even though it's conceptually terrible.

```
x = 0:10
y = sin(x) + 10

par(mar=c(5,7,4,2))
plot (
    x, y, type="o",
    xlab = "X values",
    ylab = "Y values\n",
    cex.axis = "2",
    cex.lab = "2",
    las = 1
)
```

Concerning which parameters you can set directly in `plot` have a look at `?plot.default` and `?plot.xy` as they will recieve the `...` arugments. There's also a couple of calls to undocumented functions (as far as I can find) like `localWindow` and `localBox` but I don't know what happens to them. I'd guess they're just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the mgp parameter into the title() function to avoid having to reset your defaults afterwards. That way the parameter only acts on the label(s) added by the function. like this:

```
plot (
x, y, type="o",
xlab = "",         #Don't include xlab in main plot
ylab = "Y values",
cex.axis = "2",
cex.lab = "2",
las = 1
)
title(xlab="X values"
 ,mgp=c(6,1,0))    #Set the distance of title from plot to 6 (default is 3).
```