# R - How to Remove Space between an Axis and Its Title?

Tags: r, plot

I removed the ticks and the labels from the x-axis of a plot in `R` (produced with standard graphics). Now the space between the bottom side of the plot and the title of the x-axis is huge. How to reduce it?

I am not able to implement the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506046/how-do-i-put-more-space-between-the-axis-labels-and-axis-title-in-an-r-boxplot). Thanks to anybody who can help.

Comment: Would you mind saving your plot as a .png (or some other comparable format) and add it to your post? Or possible the code used to create it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The location of the "line"-argument to `title()` controls the spacing, so:

```
 # set xlab=""   the plot call and follow with....
 title(xlab="My X-Label", line= -1)   # or 1 if you wanted it outside
```