# Why doesn't editing the margin for the x axis title text not work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

```
PESPlot <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = PESEDLessT, aes(x = Principle.Economic.Status2, y = PercentageOfPopulation, fill = "Electoral Division"), width= 0.4, 
           position = position_nudge(0.22), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = PESStateLessT, aes(x =  Principle.Economic.Status2, y = PercentageOfPopulation, fill = "Republic of Ireland"), width= 0.4,
           position = position_nudge(-0.22), stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Highest Level Of Education Completed")+
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, margin = margin(t = 0.5, unit = "in")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0)),
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "% of Population")
```

However, the distance between the X axis title and the X axis is too large. When I try to edit `axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0))` there is no changes to the distance between the x-axis and title. Can someone help me here please? Thank you

Comment: From code alone it's a bit harder to try to infer what is going on. It would be much easier if we had both (1) sample data (use `dput` please), and (2) an image of what you're seeing, so we can better visualize what is going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on reproducibility and how to best provide minimal, representative, sample data. Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506046/how-do-i-put-more-space-between-the-axis-labels-and-axis-title-in-an-r-boxplot

Answer (score 0):

Just change `t = 0.5` to `t = 0.2` or 0.3 here

```
axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, margin = margin(t = 0.5, unit = "in"))
```